# Sending mails with PHP, LAMPP and PostFix

Tags: php, lamp, postfix

I've been trying for 2 whole days now, and I just can't get the most simple thing to work.

**The problem: Sending eMails from PHP to my eMail address does not work**

I've been working with *Windows* and *Sendmail* (Sendmail was within the XAMPP package) before and everything was OK. The XAMPP-package (1.7.7) for Linux doesn't have Sendmail integrated though. So after googling around a little I found out that *Postfix* fits better into a LAMPP-environment.

---

**What I have tried so far:**

I've installed *Postfix* and wanted to configure it to just **use the smtp-server of my private eMail provider** (like it did on Windows). So I've confogured my **php.ini** like this:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
;SMTP = localhost
;smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

sendmail_path = /etc/postfix
mail.add_x_header = On
```

Note that I've commented out the "Win32 only"-stuff. The **/etc/postfix/main.cf** Looks like this:

```
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_password
myhostname = ubuntu
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
sender_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical
mydestination = ubuntu, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = mail.gmx.net
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
```

**/etc/aliases** is unchanged:

```
# Required aliases
postmaster: root
MAILER-DAEMON:  postmaster

# Common aliases
abuse:      postmaster
spam:       postmaster
```

**/etc/postfix/sasl_password**:

```
my.providers.smtp my_login:my_password
```

**/etc/postfic/sender_canonical:**

```
postmaster my.email@ddress.com
```

---

**What happens:**

So when I do

```
> sudo /etc/init.d/postfix start
```

everything seems to work fine and the **/var/log/mail.log** says: *"ubuntu postfix/master[9720]: daemon started -- version 2.8.5, configuration /etc/postfix"*

But when I run my PHP-script (which worked fine with Windows and Sendmail), it just runs through and nothing happens, not even an error is logged.

---

**What I actually want to achieve:**

I'm working locally on an e-commerce website. It runs fine on the dedicated webserver, but I want to also have it running locally for obvious reasons. In some cases, it sends emails, and I just want to be able to receive them with Thunderbird or in any other way. Is using *Postfix* overkill here? I don't need to receive emails - I just want to make the sent mails visible somehow. I could not seem to find any helpful step-by-step-tutorials for this issue (neither concerning Senmail nor Postfix - but, to be honest, I'm very new to Linux).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your php.ini, this:

```
sendmail_path = /etc/postfix
```

Should be the path to the sendmail (or compatible) binary.
You've set it to the configuration directory of postfix which isn't right.

For historical reasons, usually `/usr/bin/sendmail` is maintained as a compatibility link.
`sendmail` was around first (I guess) and pretty much everything just assumes it is in the installed MTA. So when it isn't, the replacement makes a symlink so that nothing breaks.

Comment: Thank you soooo much! Even though I don't quite understand why and in what way Sendmail and Postfix work together - it works now! Can't remember where I read about setting it to postfix, but this is the correct setting in my case: `sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"`

Comment: Added a little more info - basically they're not working together as such, you don't have sendmail, but postfix is pretending to be, because so much stuff expects it to be there :) You could equally set the sendmail_path to point at the postfix binary.

Comment: I remember! sendmail had bug after bug after bug after bug for years on end. At one point, you could include a root-only command in your ~/.forward, send yourself a mail, and do whatever on a Unix/Linux system. There was mass Exodus, and new mail servers  included a sendmail-like program designed to behave like sendmail so that all of the other programs which had built themselves around sendmail would still work with no additional effort.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the additional information! It all makes more sense now ;) I'd give you another +1 if I could, but I hope someone else who finds this just as helpful will do it for me :-D

Answer (score 1):

To send mail from localhost (WAMP, XAMP, or LAMP) you can use PHPMailer package

- Click here to download from github https://github.com/shashidhark/PhpMailer and
  Follow the instruction given in the readme file.

This will be same instruction given in readme file..

WAMP (windows):

First you have to edit the "php.ini"
To find this file display the phpinfo by using following code from the WAMP server.
Create one php file [setting.php] inside C:/wamp/www/ and add the following content to that file.

```
<?php
     echo phpinfo();
?>
```

Type **localhost/setting.php** at browser.
There search for "Loaded Configuration File" That will be the path to your **php.ini**.

In **php.ini** file remove the ;(semi colon) given to `extension=php_openssl.dll.
Now server setting is over...

- After downloading PHPMailer folder from github,
- Extract->Copy the full folder into your project folder i.e C:/wamp/www/
- Find the index.php file.
- Change the parameter as your need.
- Then in the browser type **localhost/PHPMailer/index.php**.
- Then it will show successful message if email sent, else it will give error message.

LAMP (Linux):

- In case of linux, There is no need to edit the php.ini file as i
  explained first point under WAMP.
- One more change is project or Document root folder is different.
- In Linux the default Document root folder will be /var/www
- You can change the Document root folder easily. For that visit https://stackoverflow.com/a/17612396/1925943
- Copy the PhpMailer to this document root folder and edit index.php as your need.
- Then type **localhost/PhpMailer/index.php** in browser.

Answer (score 0):

To send email (with sendmail package) through Gmail from localhost please check [PHP+Ubuntu Send email using gmail form localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969783/phpubuntu-send-email-using-gmail-form-localhost/45125490#45125490) is possible another answer.